# Nginx bug or feature?

Tags: nginx, apache2

Config 1 with Host header replacement:

```
  location /phpinfo {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;              
  }

curl -s -o /dev/null -D - http://192.168.56.102/phpinfo
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 21 Jun 2020 13:12:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 323
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://192.168.56.102:8000/phpinfo/
```

Config 2 just proxy_pass:

```
  location /phpinfo {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;              
  }


curl -s -o /dev/null -D - http://192.168.56.102/phpinfo
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 21 Jun 2020 13:25:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 313
Location: http://192.168.56.102/phpinfo/
Connection: keep-alive
```

Summary:
Linux localhost 5.4.47-0-virt #1-Alpine SMP Thu, 18 Jun 2020 14:54:31 UTC x86_64 Linux
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0

proxy_pass with Host header replacement when no trailing slash defined redirects to:

```
http://192.168.56.102:8000/phpinfo/
```

Expected:

```
Location: http://192.168.56.102/phpinfo/
```

Is this a feature?
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is caused by the backend server (apache2). It returns redirect 301 when uri is without slash at the end. So there is 2 solutions:

1. Change backend server behavior.
2. Use nginx proxy_redirect directive:

   location / {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_redirect http://$host:8000/ /;
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
   }